# Mockito spy on a HSQLDB connection

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, hsqldb

I am writing test cases for some code that uses HSQLDB to get its data from. However, there is a certain query/function called by my DAO which isn't supported in the in-memory database.

I am trying to return a custom `ResultSet` when this specific query is fired and default on the normal behavior otherwise (fetching from in memory database).

Relevant pieces of code:

```
db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addScript("resources/create-test-db.sql")
    .addScript("resources/add-test-data.sql").build();
Connection conn = Mockito.spy(db.getConnection());

PreparedStatement mockPreparedStatement = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class); 
when(conn.prepareStatement(query)).thenReturn(mockPreparedStatement);
```

And I pass on `conn` to my object. However, it seems HSQL is actually trying to run the query and thus, I get an error.

How should I do this?

Comment: You could extract this query into a method and mock that method.

Comment: What are you testing? If you're testing the DAO, then mocking the connection and the prepared statement and the resultset won't test anything of your code. And if you test a service using the DAO, then you should mock the DAO, not the connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am testing a service which calls this DAO. The current implementation is such that passing a mock DAO isn't an option. Hence, my approach

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [doReturn()](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) when mocking spies.

```
doReturn(mockPreparedStatement).when(conn).prepareStatement(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Important gotcha on spying real objects!**
>
> Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use when(Object) for stubbing spies.
> Therefore when using spies please consider doReturn|Answer|Throw() family of methods for stubbing.

Example:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);
//Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)
when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");
//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

Source: [Mockito Documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

So in your case, try this:

```
doReturn(mockPreparedStatement).when(conn).prepareStatement(query);
```